# How to pass navigation from stackNavigator to screen component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have this navigation tree:

```
var NiceTab1 = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        Tab_1: StackNav,
        Tab_2: StackNav,
        Tab_3: StackNav,
        Tab_4: StackNav,
        Tab_5: StackNav,
        Tab_6: StackNav,
        Tab_7: StackNav,
    }
}
```

StackNav:

```
var StackNav= createStackNavigator({
  FirstScreen: {
    screen: ()=><MyScreen/>,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  }
}
```

MyScreen:

```
class MyScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{HERE I NEED TO SHOW THE TOP BAR NAVIGATOR ROUTE NAME (navigation.state.routeName)}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I pass the top bar navigation to screen component if I have the StackNavigator between?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: In this situation you should be able to access to `navigation` prop into your `MyScreen` component because that component is part of the navigation...try and let me know!

Comment: Thanks, i tryed but in MyScreen in props i have the navigation of StackNavigator, i need the navigation of topBarNavigator

Comment: Wrap the root navigation by createAppContainer. Ex: export default createAppContainer(NiceTab1)